# Why supersymmetry requires either left or right movers to vanish for a $S^1$ compactification

Tags: string-theory, supersymmetry

In the chapter on Black holes in string theory (Section 11.4, page 584 near equation 11.94) in the book by Becker, Becker and Schwarz, they write

> [...] let us consider a single string wound $Q_1 Q_5$
>   times around a circle of radius $R$ that is only allowed to oscillate in four
>   transverse directions. The question to be answered is how many different
>   ways are there of constructing a supersymmetric excitations of energy $n/R$.
>   The string can have left-moving and right-moving excitations, and the level-
>   matching condition is $N_L − N_R = nW$ , where the winding number is $W = Q_1 Q_5$.
>
> Supersymmetry requires that either $N_L$ or $N_R$ vanishes, since then that
>   sector contributes a short (supersymmetric) representation in the tensor
>   product of left-movers and right-movers that gives the physical states of the
>   closed string. Whether $N_L$ or $N_R$ should vanish is determined by the sign
>   of $nW$.

I don't understand why either the left movers or the right movers need to vanish for a supersymmetric spectrum. Can somebody explain this to me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The explanation lies in the fact that you want to consider BPS states, or equivalently, short supersymmetric multiplets, because you are dealing with an extremal black hole. Now you could ask why we want to impose this restriction on the spectrum. The answer is that results based on the BPS spectrum can be generalized from weak coupling to strong coupling. If you are interested in a non-extremal black hole, then both $N_L$ and $N_R$ can be non-vanishing, as in equation (11.105) in the textbook by Becker, Becker and Schwarz.

You can find a detailed analysis of the condition that being BPS imposes on the number of left and right movers below equation (8.124). Also, exercise 8.2 shows explicitly that when the BPS bound is saturated, the number of states in a supersymmetric multiplet decreases.

Comment: Thanks, that explains it quite well. I went through the section of equation (8.124) and exercise 8.2 and I think it is clear now.